# How to cast Handle<Value> to bool

Tags: embedded-v8

I tried this:

```
Handle<Boolean> B = arg[0];
```

Compiler:

```
fatal error: assigning
    to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' 
    from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
```

Me:

```
Handle<Boolean> B = Handle<Boolean>::Cast(arg[0]);
```

Compiler:

```
fatal error: no member named 'Cast' in 'v8::Boolean'
    return Handle<T>(T::Cast(*that));
```

Me:

```
bool B = Handle<Number>::Cast(js_call(callback, 1))->Value();
```

Compiler:

```
ok
```

But this seems like a hack to me, is there a legitimate way of getting `boolean` value?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert arg[0] as a Local<Value> to a Local<Boolean>, then this will work:

```
Local<Boolean> B = arg[0].ToBoolean();
```

Worst case, you'll get an empty Local<Boolean>. If you want a bool, then use:

```
bool B = arg[0].BooleanValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Handle<Value> Val` use `Val->BooleanValue()`. You can check whether `Val` is indeed boolean with `Assert(Val->IsBoolean(), "Expected boolean")`.